# Best way to get in-app purchases donated to non-profits?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment, applepay

I'd like to develop an app that shows in-app ads. To remove the ads, I'd like to present the user with a list of non-profits that they can make a one-time donation to. I'm not sure what the best way is to implement this.

ApplePay supports allowing one-time [payments to non-profits](https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-nonprofits/), however I'd like this functionality to work more like in-app purchases where the user can restore their purchase if they use the app on another device rather than have to pay a second time.

I looked at [ApplePay's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/get-started/) and it doesn't appear as though there's any sort of built in behavior for this. Also, it's unclear if I can have one app make payments to multiple different non-profits.

The [documentation for In-App Purchases](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html) makes it look like the payment would have to go to the developer account linked to the app, but I'd prefer for the payment to go to directly to the non-profit rather than to my developer account so the user can get a guarantee that their money is going to the right place.

Does anyone know if there's a solution out there for behavior like this? I'm open to using other payment system's besides Apple's as long as there's a mechanism to validate their purchase if they install the app on a new device, preferably without having to log in, and the money goes directly to the non-profit.

Comment: Your app couldn't use ApplePay for donations anyway; only the non-profit's own app can do this. You will probably need to provide a number of different non-consumable in-app purchase items and describe which non-profit will receive the proceeds and then arrange the donations yourself

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11 for the reply. I'm still hoping to find a payment system that will make it transparent to the user where their money is going, rather than trusting that my app will send it to the right place. I'm going to start looking into ways I can use alternative payment methods like PayPal.

Comment: I think if your payment unlocks functionality in your app (including removing ads) then you will neee to use in-app purchase or face rejection